# C# WPF application launches in Visual, but not when ran directly

Tags: c#, wpf, crash

I'm making a WPF apllication and it works how it's supposed to but ONLY when I run it inside Visual Studio.

If I navigate to the folder and run it from there, it just crashes without any kind of message.

Here is a video demonstration: http://youtu.be/gVONAT387VQ

This application worked fine before when it was in 0.9. From that point on I only added a new Grid, started using Properties.Settings.Default and added a handler for ReadOnly files (because this application reads and then writes a configuration file). And none of these seem like they would cause this issue.

Edit:

Reason was found. Event viewer wrote the error out.

Part of the messagebox with handled exception I just implemented:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: The invocation of the constructor on type 'DayZ_Config_Tweak_tool.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraint threw an exception. ---> System.FormatException: Token is not valid.
at MS.Internal.Parsers.ParseBrush(String brush, IFormatPRovider formatProvider, ITypeDescriptorContext contex)
at System.Windows.Media.Brush.Parse(String value, ITypeDescriptorContext context)
at System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter:ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
at DayZ_Config_Tweak_Tool.MainWindow.InitializeButtons() in #Path to xaml.cs#:line 222
at DayZ_Config_Tweak_tool.MainWindow..ctor() in #Path to xaml.cs#:line 44
```

Comment: Could it be that the file is being read from a different directory?  I.e. You may have specified a relative path?

Comment: .NET will have recorded the crash in the Windows event log. The event usually says what type of exception caused the crash.

Comment: @JustinHui file is absolute and is always read from same directory. As I said, application worked just fine before, no change has been made to the loading/saving procedure

Comment: @GlenThomas You're right. it did. Here are the errors: http://i.imgur.com/TmpXNPL.png and http://i.imgur.com/RD9gy4L.png
Do you know what might've caused this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My settings were hex color strings and they missed the hashtag '000000' instead of '#000000'.
During the debug running my application automatically loaded the "Dark" theme that's initialized immediately after the application launches, however this did not occur once the application was ran outside of dev environment for one reason or another.
Adding the hashtag fixed the issue.

Basically running the application outside Devenv means your Properties.Settings.Default will be empty!! Checking for that and loading it before InitializeComponent(); fixed all issues!